# Image to base64

Tags: java, android

How can I convert all the images stored in one folder to `base64` data? in the following code `tFotos` is the folder where all my images are stored.

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"tFotos");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
mList.add(StrBase64);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ruben JG 
You have to provide full path of image like sdcard/foldername/filename.PNG/.JPEG